# Power Query Date Table - Change Range to Two Years

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I want to make the date range span two years and not one. However the duration.days function appears to be limiting it to one. I want to keep this though, this way the table will automatically update each day with today's date.

How can I increase the range to two years?

```
Query1(#date(2017,1,1),Duration.Days(DateTime.Date(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()) - #date(2017,1,1)) + 1, #duration(1,0,0,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct and now working as expected:

```
Query1(#date(2017,1,1),Duration.Days(DateTime.Date(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()) - #date(2018,1,1)) + 1, #duration(1,0,0,0))
```